# Split substring from string and count till next character

Tags: c#, regex, string, linq

I have a string like this ..

```
2931 8795  012 00:24:14 06/03/13 10:03 O006129009857       **     0           0
```

Now as per my requirement i have to split the substrings like `2931`,`06/03/13` and `O006129009857`.I have used `IndexOf` method of string to get the start and end index of substring as soon as a empty space comes like this in the code..

```
 int startIndex = line.IndexOf(Calldate);
 int endIndex = line.IndexOf(" ", startIndex);
 int difference = endIndex - startIndex;
 strSubstring = (startIndex + "," + difference);
```

As we can see to endIndex i have taken `line.IndexOf(" ", startIndex);` while now i want to take next character for Example if i have to take `O006129009857` then i have to count till `**` or any other character available at that place  to calculate the `endIndex`..

Please help me to calculate the `endIndex` till next character comes instead of .
Please help me .Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

```
^(\d+)|(\d+\/\d+\/\d+)|\b(\w\d+)\b(?=\s*\*\*)
```

Try this.just grab the captures.see demo.

http://regex101.com/r/qC9cH4/14

Comment: I want to calculate the `endIndex` till next character comes instead of space .How to calculate the `endIndex`  till next character instead of space as present this time..?

Comment: int startIndex = line.IndexOf(Calldate); will give me the start index of substring Calldate in the given full string.int endIndex = line.IndexOf(" ", startIndex); will give the character count of the substring till it gets empty space.Now i need to have the character count till another character comes instead of my present delimiter i.e space.Can you tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The string.Split function will accomplish this for you:

```
        string text = "2931 8795  012 00:24:14 06/03/13 10:03 O006129009857       **    0           0";
        char[] Delimiters = new char[]{' '};
        var result = text.Split(new char[]{' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

The result will be 
2931
8795
012
00:24:14
06/03/13
10:03
O006129009857
**
0
0

Comment: I want to count even space also till next character comes and add it into `endIndex` .If you know this .Please help me

Comment: Take a look at my answer @shubhamHegdey

Answer (score 0):

cant you just use string.Split(' '); to return an array of string that are seperated by a space [" "]?

```
string CallDate = "2931 8795  012 00:24:14 06/03/13 10:03 O006129009857       **     0           0    ";
string[] parts = CallDate.Split(' ');
parts = parts.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)).ToArray();
```

Your parts array looks like

```
{"2931", "8795", "012", "00:24:14", "06/03/13", "10:03", "O006129009857", "**", "0", "0"}
```

EDIT: To count the spaces between words, remove the line

```
parts = parts.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)).ToArray();
```

and your array looks like

```
"2931", "8795", "", "012", "00:24:14", "06/03/13", "10:03", "O006129009857", "", "", "", "", "", "", "**", "", "", "", "", "0", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "0", "", "", "", ""
```

The number of empty spaces between each word is the number of empty strings between each non-empty string. a simple for loop over the array will allow you to count the spaces (and therefore the position of each work in the string.

Comment: `int startIndex = line.IndexOf(Calldate);` will give me the start index of substring `Calldate` in the given full string.`int endIndex = line.IndexOf(" ", startIndex);` will give the character count of the substring till it gets empty space.Now i need to have the character count till another character comes instead of my present delimiter i.e space.Can you tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear what you are asking but if I understand correctly, you want to calculate the number between a specific index in a string and the next character that is not a space. The following code assumes that you want to know the number of characters between foo and bar but that you know the start index.

```
string input = "foo     bar";
int startIndex = 3;
string pattern = @"\S";
var regex = new Regex(pattern);
int endIndex = regex.Match(input, startIndex).Index;
int characterCount = endIndex - startIndex;
```